# I am creating 24hr period value. dont work mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create 24hr period from database creation date with this code but I have mysql_fetch_assoc problem when I want to echo dif its show wrong format I need just secounds!

```
//connect to database
//.... 

//get time difference in seconds from last execution
$sql1 = "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_ts)) AS tdif FROM php_cron";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die("[1] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());


while ($dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {

echo $dif["tdif"] ;

}

if ($dif >= 86400) { //24h

    //following code will run once every 24h

    //update user's page rank
    $sql2 = "UPDATE myTable SET `user-rank` = `user-rank` + 10"; 
    mysql_query($sql2) or die("[2] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

    //update last execution time
    $sql3 = "UPDATE php_cron SET last_ts = NOW() WHERE id=1";
    mysql_query($sql3) or die("[3] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

}
```

It will be better if you can access to all dates of column :)  can anyone help?

========================================================================================////////////

---

I put counter for ID. is there any other better way? thanks

```
$idcount = 1;
while ($dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
echo $dif["tdif"];
echo "<br>";

if ($dif["tdif"] >= 86400) { //24h
  //update user's page rank
  $sql2 = "UPDATE deposit SET `earn` = `earn` + 10 where id=" . $idcount . ""; 
  mysql_query($sql2) or die("[2] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: `$dif` is array. ANd you compare it to int.

Comment: `mysql_` is depracted. Use PDO (or if you must, `mysqli_`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is this is actually what you want to do. Notice I moved the `if` statement inside of the `while` loop and changed `$dif` to `$dif["tdif"]`.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_ts)) AS tdif FROM php_cron";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die("[1] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

while ($dif = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
   echo $dif["tdif"];

   if ($dif["tdif"] >= 86400) { //24h
      //update user's page rank
      $sql2 = "UPDATE myTable SET `user-rank` = `user-rank` + 10"; 
      mysql_query($sql2) or die("[2] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

      //update last execution time
      $sql3 = "UPDATE php_cron SET last_ts = NOW() WHERE id=1";
      mysql_query($sql3) or die("[3] MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());

   }
}
```

Comment: this is better but when check if for period increase all field to +10 how can increase each one? did you think is sql code wrong?